# javascript problem not allowing to open the page?

Tags: javascript

When I press the log in button it doesn't enter the page but when I remove that code of `e.preventDefault();` the page is open but the validation form doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
const email = document.getElementById('InputEmail1');
const password = document.getElementById('InputPassword1');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateInputs();
});

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const formgroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = formgroup.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
  
    formgroup.classList.add('error');
    formgroup.classList.remove('success');
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const formgroup = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = formgroup.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';

    formgroup.classList.add('success');
    formgroup.classList.remove('error');
}

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();

    if (emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, 'Email Address is required');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, 'Provide a valid email address');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if (passwordValue === '') {
        setError(password, 'Password is required');
    } else if (passwordValue.length < 8) {
        setError(password, 'Password must be at least 8 character.');
    } else {
        setSuccess(password);
    }
}
```

I tried to remove that code e.preventDefault(); but that validation form doesn't work

Comment: Validate first, then depending on the result, prevent the default or don't.